# java.util.NoSuchElementException while scanning file

Tags: java

I am reading from a file and saving everything into it. The whole program ran fine but I had not read the last line of the file and when I tried doing that is when things got weird, the last line of the file is "END_OF_FILE". I tried saving it as a String and it didn't work that's when I received the error message but now I took all that out of my code and it doesn't run the program completely, the last thing it outputs is the work yes which is in my last for loop in main.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class hurry2 {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        File candidates = new File("cipcs115.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(candidates);
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        String state = scan.next();
        int numOfCan = scan.nextInt();
        String what = scan.nextLine();

        String stateWi ;
        String stateAl ;
        String stateDe ;

        int numOfCanWi ;
        int numOfCanAl ;
        int numOfCanDe ;

        Candidate [] candiIl ;
        Candidate [] candiWi;
        Candidate [] candiAl ;
        Candidate [] candiDe;
        hurry2 cill = new hurry2();   

        candiIl = new Candidate[numOfCan];
        for ( int i=0; i<numOfCan; i++)
        {
            String three = scan.next();
            String four = scan.next();
            String five = scan.next();
            int six = scan.nextInt();
            double seven = scan.nextDouble();
            String eight = scan.nextLine();

            Candidate night  = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
            candiIl [i] = night ;
            System.out.println(night.getName() + "  " + night.getMotto());
        }

        stateWi = scan.next();
        numOfCanWi = scan.nextInt();

        candiWi = new Candidate[numOfCanWi];
        for ( int i=0; i<numOfCanWi; i++)
        {
            String three = scan.next();
            String four = scan.next();
            String five = scan.next();
            int six = scan.nextInt();
            double seven = scan.nextDouble();
            String eight = scan.nextLine();

            Candidate night  = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
            candiWi [i] = night ;
            System.out.println(night.getName() + "  " + night.getMotto());
        }

        stateAl = scan.next();
        numOfCanAl = scan.nextInt();

        candiAl = new Candidate[numOfCanAl];
        for ( int i=0; i<numOfCanAl; i++)
        {
            String three = scan.next();
            String four = scan.next();
            String five = scan.next();
            int six = scan.nextInt();
            double seven = scan.nextDouble();
            String eight = scan.nextLine();

            Candidate night  = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
            candiAl [i] = night ;
            System.out.println(night.getName() + "  " + night.getMotto());
        }

        stateDe = scan.next();
        numOfCanDe = scan.nextInt();

        candiDe = new Candidate[numOfCanDe];
        for ( int i=0; i<numOfCanAl; i++)
        {
            String three = scan.next();
            String four = scan.next();
            String five = scan.next();
            int six = scan.nextInt();
            double seven = scan.nextDouble();
            String eight = scan.nextLine();

            Candidate night  = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
            candiDe [i] = night ;
            System.out.println(night.getName() + "  " + night.getMotto());
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

        System.out.println(" what would you like to do? >");
        String option = user.next();
        switch (option)
        {
            case "m":
            case "M":
                cill.menu(candiIl);
                break;
        }
        scan.close();    
    }

    public static void menu(Candidate [] rod)
    { 
        hurry2 cill1 = new hurry2();
        Scanner menus = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print( "What would you like to do next >");
        String option1 = menus.next() ;
        switch (option1)
        { 
            case "l" :
            case "L" :
                cill1.listall(rod);
                break ;
        }
        return ;
    }
    public static void listall(Candidate [] yes)
    {
        int numOfCan = 3;
        for (int s =0; s<numOfCan;s++)
            System.out.println(yes[s].getName() + yes[s].getParty() + yes[s].getMotto());
        return ;
    }
}
```

and here is my whole error message, again this program outputs everything up to the word yes, which I included in my last for loop  for array candiDe. Thanks in advance for the help guys.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at hurry2.main(hurry2.java:91)
```

Comment: your sentences are totally mixed up and your code is too big to understand on the fly. Please change it into an MCVE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
And PLEASE use indentation, simply copy&paste the formatted text out of your IDE, most IDEs will format and indent it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are attempting for a multiple `scan.next()` method calls without checking to `scan.hasNext()` method.

Try to have `scan.hasNext()` before you call `next()` method.

Comment: well I understand that's for safety but I have know how the file is set up, and it is storing everything correctly. at the end of each look I print out each one of the values passed so I can see everything is stored right. The problem arises right before my first switch statement, the System.out.println("What would you like to do next >") is never outputted. @hemanth

Comment: Why do you have two for loops for numOfCanAl?

Answer (score 0):

> the last thing it outputs is the work yes

It seems that the loop enters, prints `yes` and in the next iteration throws the exception.
At some instant you get out of tokens to get in the scanner.